# How do I add a custom class to a storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am currently trying to implement a custom radio button class that I have been messing with (located at https://github.com/t4ku/RadioButtonWithUIKit). This radio button solution draws everything programmatically.

I was wondering if there is a similar solution using buttons that were added via Storyboard. I already have my design exactly how I want it through Storyboard and would much rather somehow "link" the buttons with my radio button class.

Any newer ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the class of an object on Storyboard in the identity inspector (you can manually enter the class instead of relying on the drop down menu).  You can then link the object however you like.

If Storyboard doesnt accept the RadioButton class for some reason you could also create a custom class of UIButton that would inherit from the RadioButton class and then use that in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

That control is based on `UIView`, so in your storyboard just add a new `View` object, select it, and then set the `class` (at the top of the image) to `RadioButton`:

[image]

You won't be able to see anything but a blank view where you place it, but it will work properly when you launch the application.  This will at least make it easier to resize, position, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @Dana K also answered my question. I will try to play around with customer classes to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, to refer to a button added to a storyboard programmatically, you have to link the variable name in your .h file to the actual button in your .xib file.  If you add the following line to your .h file

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;
```

Then when you return to the .xib, there should a yellow cube (file's owner) to the left of the storyboard panel.  If you right click on that cube, you should get a list of outlets.  At the end of the line that has your button's name, there should a circle.  If you Ctrl+Click and Hold and drag it to the button in the storyboard, it should like the variable in the .h file to the button in the storyboard.

So now when you refer to the variable name you created, you will be referring to the button in the storyboard.